# WordPress author filters

Tags: wordpress

I have added a filter on "the_author" to add some html code with author info. However all my HTML is coming under an anchor of author link. For eg:

```
add_filter( 'the_author', 'myfun');
function myfun( $content ) { 
        $content.= 'hi';
        return $content;
}
```

Now "Hi" is just a simple text which should not be included in author anchor tag. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'the_author', 'myfun' );
add_filter( 'get_the_author_display_name', 'myfun' );

function myfun( $name) {
  global $post;

  if ( $name)
    $name.= '</br>hi';


   return $name;
}
```

Comment: No it is not helping. Although I did manage to resolve the issue by including "</a>". But I believe this is not the right way.